# Pivot and Join a Table to Itself in Google Sheet Connected to BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am very new to SQL, however, I have a fair amount of experience with Google Queries, at any rate. I have recently graduated to hosting my data in BigQuery and I need to create a simple pivot of a table and then join it back to the original table.

My goal is to find a client's month/year of initial purchase and then create a column where that data will be assigned to every order they have made. (assigning them a purchasing cohort)

I have worked through how to pivot the data to output the desired table, however, I don't know how to rejoin it to the original table without actually writing it to another table in BigQuery.

Here is what I have so far, at least this is my latest attempt...

```
CREATE TABLE Cohort_List AS (
    SELECT
      MIN(CONCAT(CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR from datecreated) as string), LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from datecreated) as string),2,'0'))) as Cohort_Date,
      customerid as CL_Customer_ID,
    FROM `fishbowl_raw_data.fishbowl_so`
    GROUP BY customerid
    );
    
    SELECT
      DATE(datecreated) as SO_Date,
      customerid as Customer_ID,
      totalprice as SO_Total,
    FROM `fishbowl_raw_data.fishbowl_so`
    JOIN Cohort_List
    ON `fishbowl_raw_data.fishbowl_so`.`customerid`=Cohort_List.CL_Customer_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by creating a sample dataset:

[image]

Using the query below, I created a table Cohort_List that includes the `Common Table Expression (CTE)` that will display the `COHORT_DATE` per `customerid`. Using the CTE, I managed to join it with the `sample_data` to get the `COHORT_DATE` per `customerid`.

```
CREATE TABLE `my-project.mydataset.Cohort_List` AS (
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
  MIN(datecreated) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid) as COHORT_DATE,
  customerid
FROM `my-project.mydataset.sample_data`
)
SELECT 
  DISTINCT a.customerid as Customer_ID,
  a.datecreated as SO_Date,
  totalprice as SO_Total,
  CONCAT(CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR from b.COHORT_DATE) AS STRING), LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from b.COHORT_DATE) AS STRING), 2, '0')) as Cohort_Date
FROM `my-project.mydataset.sample_data` a
LEFT JOIN CTE b
ON a.customerid = b.customerid
ORDER BY a.customerid, a.datecreated
)
```

**Output upon querying the my-project.mydataset.Cohort_List**

[image]

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution. Thank you for helping me figure this out. I put this solution into the SQL Query in Google Sheets and it is throwing and error:

Comment: Sorry, got busy with something and didn't get that error code pasted in time...BigQuery error: Queries that modify the data source are not supported.

Comment: So I took this and put it directly into BigQuery instead and it worked perfectly!